# I can't find the downloaded libs folder

Tags: node.js, node-modules, npm-install, libs

I can't find my libs folders, I looked everywhere, I download a lib but it doesn't show up, I need help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnUKd.jpg)

Comment: Did you install it via npm? If so, what commands did you use and what was their output? Can you provide a better screenshot of the issue? This one is unreadable.

Comment: ready zoomed the image, and yes I installed it at npm, comands: npm i  lodash

Comment: Did you initalize you node project via `npm init`?

Comment: no, I'm a beginner, I don't know what this is for

Comment: for installing any packages you shoud initalize project, type command `npm init` in project dir

Comment: ouraaaa thank you, it worked <3

Answer (score 0):

In your project directory type

```
$ npm init
$ npm i loadsh
```

Comment: also check vs-code open directory, it shoud match to command line path